# Returning a list of messages

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

Given that i have multiple models, each needed to have their own create/get/get list API.
Do i need to add two different types of messages (single and list) for every model?
For example : 
If i have a student type -

```
message Student{
    string name = 1;
}
```

and a rpc:

```
rpc CreateStudent(Student) returns (google.protobuf.Empty){
         ..............    
}
```

If i'd like to add a rpc to create a list of students, or get a list of students

```
rpc CreateStudends(??????) returns (google.protobuf.Empty){
             ..............    
}

rpc GetAllStudents() returns (??????){
         ..............    
}
```

Do i need to also define

```
message StudentList{
   repeated Student students = 1;
}
```

Or is there a way to use a list type directly in the message input/output?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, basically - you would want a different message type per element type, or *maybe* a single root type with a `oneof` style content. Raw protobuf does not include a concept of generics or templates.

Some libraries do, but: that's outside of the specification.

Comment: How scalable is this? The question has a very simple message but in reality, a student record would be significantly larger, and there could be a large volume of records.  If this were a REST API, would you expect a method where an entire dataset is uploaded in a single JSON object?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add the `stream` keyword to your RPCs. No need to define a message field as repeated, `stream` will send or receive multiple independent messages.

```
message Student {
    string name = 1;
}
```

with RPCs:

```
rpc CreateStudent(Student) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {
         ..............    
}

rpc CreateStudents(stream Student) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {
             ..............    
}

rpc GetAllStudents() returns (stream Student) {
         ..............    
}
```

It's good practice to send/stream a response object rather than empty. Otherwise, you only have the gRPC response code to indicate a problem and will need to reference the logs to debug.

Comment: IMO that's a bad idea. A stream is semantically separate to a message with a repeated element, and this could lead to very inefficient implementations. Streams are for multiple separate response frames, not to emulate repeated.

Comment: I think a lot depends on the application and implementation. If looking to batch upload 100k records, a message containing a repeated field would take a huge amount of memory, and one error could result in the whole batch being rejected; or worse it failing midway through processing.  Streaming allows you to send individual records and receive independent responses.  The only consideration is that a streamed response may not be in the order of the streamed input.